# Regular expression for DBContext.Database.Log

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, regex, entity-framework

I have sql code that was generated `bymyDBcontext.Database.Log = s => myTextWriter(s)` :

```
INSERT [dbo].[Commodities]([IsGas], [IsPower], [Name])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Commodities]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()

-- @0: 'True' (Type = Boolean)
-- @1: 'False' (Type = Boolean)
-- @2: 'Gas' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- Executing at 24.6.2015 13:20:32 +02:00
-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader

--
--Other Inserts here
--
```

I would like to execute this SQL query on my testing server. Unfortunately this sql code isn't executable. I need something like this:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Commodities]([IsGas], [IsPower], [Name])
VALUES (1, 0, 'Gas')
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Commodities]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
```

Could you give me advice how to process this sql (with regular expressions I guess) so that it began to be executable?

Comment: If you only need the first 5 lines, you don't need regex for that. What's in "Other Insers here"?

Comment: @greenfeet, I also thought that, but the 2nd line has parameters whos vaues are inside the comments section below the command. I am guessing the OP is looking for a way to take the values from the comments and "regex" them into the command

Comment: Why did you go the route of logging the queries like this and not use the SQLProfiler, with which you can then replay the give commands at a later stage and see the actual executed commands with their values all in one statement.

Comment: @ Bernd Linde makes sense, I missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all lines starting with `--` and empty lines, and then use the values from the comments inserted to the `VALUES` line.

The following code might be of help:

```
var rxGetValues = new Regex(@"(?ms)(?<=^VALUES\s+\([^)]*?)@(?<id>\d+)(?=.*?^-{2}\s+@\k<id>:\s+'(?<val>[^']*)')");
var str = "YOUR_STRING";
str = rxGetValues.Replace(str, m => m.Groups["val"].Value.ToLower() == "false" 
                               || m.Groups["val"].Value.ToLower() == "true" ? 
                Convert.ToInt32(Boolean.Parse(m.Groups["val"].Value)).ToString() 
              : m.Groups["val"].Value);
str = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, str.Split(new[] { "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(p => !p.Trim().StartsWith("--")).ToArray());
```

Result:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Commodities]([IsGas], [IsPower], [Name])
VALUES (1, 0, Gas)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Commodities]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
```